# SQL Scalar UDF to get number of days in Year

Tags: t-sql, variables, user-defined-functions

I writing code to determine how many days in a year. I am trying to keep it really simple. 
I found code that I think is very clean to determine a leap year. I am passing the inputted date using DATEPART(Y,@Year) to the leap year program and some how am not getting the correct results so I has to be in my SQL code to process the input date as the correct bit is returned.

Here is the code for the Leap Year:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Is_Leap_Year]
(
 -- the parameters for the function here

        @year int
)

RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (select case datepart(mm, dateadd(dd, 1, cast((cast(@year as varchar(4)) + '0228') as datetime)))
WHEN 2 THEN 1
ELSE 0  END)

END
```

Here is the code I wrote to process the input date & get the # days in a year:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Get_Days_In_Year]
(
    @InputDT    varchar(10)
)

RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE  @Result  int,
         @Year    int   


Set @Result = 
 CASE
    WHEN dbo.FN_Is_Leap_Year(Datepart(yyyy,@Year)) = 0 Then 365
    WHEN dbo.FN_Is_Leap_Year(Datepart(yyyy,@Year)) = 1 Then 366
 END


        RETURN @Result
    END
```

Comment: in the last section of code, why call the function (dbo.FN_Is_Leap_Year) 2 times in the `CASE` statement? you should use `CASE dbo.FN_Is_Leap_Year(Datepart(yyyy,@Year)) WHEN 0 THEN 365 ELSE 366 END`.  Heck, I'd dump the first function and just pull its one line of code into the `CASE`.

Comment: `SELECT 1 + DATEDIFF(day, CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-01-01', CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-12-31');` ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!!

```
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Get_Days_In_Year]
(
    @InputDT     int
)

RETURNS varchar(3)
AS
BEGIN

Declare     @Year    int,   
            @RetVal  bit,
            @Result varchar(3)

    Set @Year   = datepart(yy, @InputDT)
    Set @RetVal = dbo.FN_Is_Leap_Year(Datepart(yy,'2012'))  
    Set @Result = CASE @RetVal
                      WHEN 1 THEN 366
                      ELSE 365 
                  End    
    Return @Result
END
```

Comment: Good. I don't understand what's going on with your types though. It should return an int not varchar(3) and accept a date datatype. Also unless you are using this in a lot of places I'd probably dispense with the UDF for this and use something like `CASE WHEN Col1 % 4 > 0 THEN 365 WHEN Col1 % 400 = 0 THEN 366 WHEN Col1 % 100 = 0 THEN 365 ELSE 366 END`

Comment: Nope I am wrong, i Validated the bit is passing okay, but the code is still not returning correctly, any help is appreciated.

GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Get_Days_In_Year]
(
    @InputDT  int
 )
 
RETURNS varchar(3)
AS
BEGIN

Declare     @Year    int,   
      @RetVal  bit,
      @Result varchar(3)
 
Set @Year = datepart(yy, @InputDT)

Set @RetVal = dbo.FN_Is_Leap_Year(Datepart(yy,@Year))  
Set @Result = 
 Case When @RetVal = 1 then 365 Else 366
   end
  
 
 Return @Result
END

Comment: Martin, I am sorry I am not totally follow your Case statement can you elaborate?

Comment: Martin, I have working through you code:

CASE WHEN Col1 % 4 > 0 THEN 365 WHEN Col1 % 400 = 0 THEN 366 WHEN Col1 % 100 = 0 THEN 365 ELSE 366 END

got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of the above answer :

```sql
DECLARE @year INT,
        @DaysInYear INT
SET @year = 2011

SELECT @DaysInYear = CASE DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(dd, 1, CAST((CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0228') AS DATETIME))) 
            WHEN 2 THEN 366 ELSE 365  END 

SELECT @DaysInYear 'DaysInYear'
```